# Object method reference - how pass?

Tags: php

How can I pass referecnce of object method to variable?
I have no idea, tried everything.

```
class CObject
{
    public function method($param)
    {
        return $param;
    }
}

$obj = new CObject();
$a = $obj->method; //doesn't work, here I was trying to pass method reference of object to this variable
```

Comment: this should help you: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: it would be helpful if I can pass call method without object instance, just like `$a('param')` and will call `$obj->method('param')`

Comment: you can. $m = "method"; $obj->$m() would call $obj->method();

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pass a reference to the method.  Because of the way PHP handles callbacks, all you need is an object reference and the method name as a string.

```
class AnObject 
{
    public function aMethod( $param )
    {
        return $param . ' was here';
    }
}

$method = 'aMethod';
$object = new AnObject( );
$param = 'fourty two';

// outputs: string(19) "fourty two was here"
var_dump( $object->{$method}($param) ); 

// also outputs: string(19) "fourty two was here"
var_dump( call_user_func( array( $object, $method ), $param ) );
```

If you're trying to pass a reference to a callback, you're most likely looking for this (according to your original example) :

```
$a = array( $object, 'method' );
```

Then you can call that method with a parameter:

```
$result = call_user_func( $a, 'my parameter' );
```

The docs ([call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)) explain more.

Answer (score 1):

PHP enforces referencing functions through the [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) mechanism.

If you want to keep a reference to a method for later invocation, you could simply do this

```
$obj = new CObject();
$myMethod = array($obj,'method');
```

and invoke it later with [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) :

```
$result = call_user_func($myMethod,$someArgument);
```

The callable reference does not encapsulate the method but rather a call to the method in the context of a specific instance of the class ($obj in this case).

Alternatively, there's a [reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) that could be used to reference a method (quite like Java does).

```
$obj = new CObject();
$cObjClass = new ReflectionClass($obj);
try{
   $myMethod = $cObjClass->getMethod('method');
   $myMethod->invoke($obj,$someArgument);
}catch(ReflectionException $e){
  //the method does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second answer:

```
class CObject
{
    public function method($param)
    {
        return $param;
    }
}

$obj = new CObject();
$a = $obj->method('value');
echo $a;
```

Classic mistake:

```
$a = function($param) { return $param; }; //lambda function passed to variable
echo $a('param');
```

you forgot a ;

Comment: nope, it was only example even I forgot semicolon, I want to pass object method to variable, not lambda function

Comment: you don't have any objects there only primitives, can you explain the expected result?

Comment: do u see ask title? dont wan't to call method, I want to pass this method as reference to $a variable